# syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' (View: C:\project\laravel\project1\app\resources\views\products.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error when I try to read the data inside a view that returned by controller.
I tried to change it many times but I still get same result

This is the controller index function where I launch the query and view

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' (View: C:\project\laravel\project1\app\resources\views\products.blade.php)

```
public function index()
{
    $data = DB::table('product')->get();
    return view('products',["products"=>$data]);
}
```

and this is the view part where I try to parse it:

```
<ul>
@foreach (products as product )
    <li>{{ product->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

if you have any idea or suggestion that s will be nice , thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables on PHP start with a `$` sign. The `$products` and `$product` are variables so try to fix your code like this:

```php
<ul>
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <li>{{ $product->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Please check the [Laravel templating docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops)

Comment: thanks bro I forgot it cause I m coming from JS , thanks again